# Error in pgfplots foreach syntax column index

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am using [Texmaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texmaker). What's wrong with *"x index = \t+1"*?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
        1,2,3,4,5
        4,5,6,7,8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \t in {1,2,3}
            \addplot+ table [col sep=comma, x index=\t+1, y index=0] {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And it returns the following error message:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the requested column number '1+1' in table 'data.txt' does not exist!? Please verify you used the correct index 0 <= i < N..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `\t+1` need to be evaluated before being passed to `x index`.

Usually this can be done with `x index/.evaluated=\t+1`, but here `pgfplots` turns on floating-point evaluation inside `axis` environment, hence the evaluated result of `\t+1` would be the floating-point representation of `2.0`.

Besides looping from `\t = 2`, here two extra attempts are provided:

1. Use a manual calculation with primitive `\numexpr`: `x index/.expanded=\the\numexpr \t+1`.
2. Define a new key `.evaluated to int` and use it as `.evaluated to int=\t+1`.

```tex
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{data.txt}
        1,2,3,4,5
        4,5,6,7,8
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.evaluated to int/.code=
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/pgf/fpu/.@cmd}
      {\pgfkeys@mathparse{#1}%
       \pgfmathfloattoint{\pgfmathresult}%
       \expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}}
      {\pgfkeys@error{You have to load `fpu' to use handler `.evaluated to int'}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \t in {1,2,3}
      \addplot+ table [col sep=comma, x index/.expanded=\the\numexpr\t+1, y index=0] {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \t in {1,2,3}
      \addplot+ table [col sep=comma, x index/.evaluated to int=\t+1, y index=0] {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @muzimuzhi Z